# sonarqube updatecenter error We're sorry, but something went wrong

Tags: java, sonarqube, sonarqube-5.0

When I click Configuration -> Update Center, I got a page "We're sorry, but something went wrong.
Please try back in a few minutes and contact support if the problem persists."

I can see the following error in sonar.log:

```
2015.07.15 16:35:33 ERROR web[o.s.s.ui.JRubyFacade]  Fail to render: http://localhost:9000/updatecenter
undefined method `clean_message' for #<Java::JavaLang::NoClassDefFoundError:0x4de2e1ad>
On line #7 of gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/templates/rescues/diagnostics.erb

4:     in <%=h request.parameters['controller'].humanize %>Controller<% if request.parameters['action'] %>#<%=h request.parameters['action'] %><% end %>
5:   <% end %>
6: </h1>
7: <pre><%=h @exception.clean_message %></pre>
8: 
9: <%= render :file => @rescues_path["rescues/_trace.erb"] %>
10: 

gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/templates/rescues/diagnostics.erb:7
org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:2227:in `send'
gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_view/renderable.rb:34:in `render'
gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_view/base.rb:306:in `with_template'
gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_view/renderable.rb:30:in `render'
gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_view/template.rb:205:in `render_template'
gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_view/base.rb:265:in `render'
gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/rescue.rb:133:in `rescue_action_locally'
gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/rescue.rb:152:in `rescue_action_without_handler'
gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/rescue.rb:73:in `rescue_action'
gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/rescue.rb:162:in `perform_action_with_rescue'
gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/rescue.rb:160:in `perform_action_with_rescue'
gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/flash.rb:151:in `perform_action_with_flash'
org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:2235:in `send'
gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/base.rb:532:in `process'
gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/filters.rb:606:in `process_with_filters'
gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/base.rb:391:in `process'
gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/base.rb:386:in `call'
gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/routing/route_set.rb:450:in `call'
gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:87:in `dispatch'
gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:85:in `dispatch'
gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:121:in `_call'
gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:130:in `build_middleware_stack'
org/jruby/RubyProc.java:290:in `call'
org/jruby/RubyProc.java:224:in `call'
gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:29:in `call'
gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:34:in `cache'
gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:9:in `cache'
gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:28:in `call'
gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:361:in `call'
gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/string_coercion.rb:25:in `call'
gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/params_parser.rb:15:in `call'
file:/F:/Program Files/sonarqube-5.0/sonarqube-5.0/lib/server/jruby-rack-1.1.13.2.jar!/jruby/rack/session_store.rb:70:in `context'
gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/failsafe.rb:26:in `call'
gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:106:in `call'
file:/F:/Program Files/sonarqube-5.0/sonarqube-5.0/lib/server/jruby-rack-1.1.13.2.jar!/rack/adapter/rails.rb:34:in `serve_rails'
file:/F:/Program Files/sonarqube-5.0/sonarqube-5.0/lib/server/jruby-rack-1.1.13.2.jar!/rack/adapter/rails.rb:39:in `call'
file:/F:/Program Files/sonarqube-5.0/sonarqube-5.0/lib/server/jruby-rack-1.1.13.2.jar!/rack/handler/servlet.rb:22:in `call'
```

Im using the Sonaqube 5.0, java 8 and mysql 5.6 server. It is working very well for past 1 year. Today I tired to check for updates and i got this error. Please help me on this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose your problem is about upgrading SonarQube itself, not plugins?
Have you read the upgrade notes http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Release+5.1+Upgrade+Notes?

It might be necessary to remove some plugins before upgrading SomarQube http://qualilogy.com/en/sonarqube-upgrade/.

Hope it helps.
Regards.

Comment: My case is when I click on "Update Center" I'm getting the above error. I'm sure its not a plugin probs.